# BottomNavigationView, переключение между activity или фрагментами

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity, android-intent

Здравствуйте. Я только начинающий и прошу не судить строго и помочь. Проблема состоит в том, что у меня 3 кнопки на BottomNavigationView и вопрос в том, как реализовать переключение, то есть чтобы по нажатию кнопки выводилась другая информация, нужно ли создавать другие activity ? Еще проблема в том, что при нажатии первой кнопки должна выводиться GoogleMap. Далее привожу код.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                Intent intent_maps = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent_maps);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                Intent intent_routes = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RoutesActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent_routes);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                Intent intent_history = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, HistoryActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent_history);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

};
```

Как правильно это сделать?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

[В Google](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#) пишут, что можно использовать как для прямого доступа к компоненту приложения (activity), так и для переключения между табами, например. Решайте сами, в зависимости от логики Вашего приложения.

 Помните, что при создании Activity, в ней нужно будет делать свой компонент BottomNavigation (если он нужен, конечно).

 Если нужно, чтобы BottomNavigation всегда был внизу один и тот же, лучше использовать фрагменты или табы.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ. Но особую сложность для меня составляет то, что в активности MapsActivity выводится карта Google с точками, полученными из файла JSON (public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback). У меня не получается оформить активность в виде фрагмента, т.к. не работает метод для считывания из JSON.(JsonObjectRequest из библиотеки Volley)